# reading special characters text from .ini file in python

Tags: python, configparser

I am running a script which takes a text "rAh%19u^l\&G" i.e which contains special characters as seen.

When i pass this text in my script as a argument it runs fine without any error.

example - : `./abc.py <username><pwd>`

The above text is basically a password.

Now, when i place my values in a config file and read the above text, **the script fails**.

*******abc.ini *******

```
[DEFAULT]
username = rahul
pwd =  rAh%19u^l\&G
```

it says

```
/bin/sh:M command not found.
```

Reading the above values with help of config parser

******Below is the program abc.py  ******

```
#! /usr/bin/python

parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('abc.ini')
username = parser.get('DEFAULT','username')
pwd = parser.get('DEFAULT','pwd')


p = subprocess.Popen(
    "abc.py {0} {1}" .format(username, pwd), 
    shell=True, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)

out, err = p.communicate()

print(out)
```

I tried searching a lot but found nothing concrete.

So the question is how to read a text that contains special characters in a .ini file.

Comment: Don't format code with backticks in questions. Instead indent by 4 spaces (with leading newline). You can do this automatically by highlighting your code and pressing the `{}` button at the top.

Comment: Have you tried quoting it as in `pwd = "rAh%19u^l\&G"` or escaping the backslash as in `pwd = "rAh%19u^l\\&G"` - btw, what is the value of `username` and `pwd`, can you print them before calling the other script?

Comment: @PauloScardine - i tried rAh%19u^l\\&G by using  backslash but it didn't work out.i didn't tried quoting it. But while quoting it won't it take quotes also as complete text ??

Comment: Try that and tell us... :-)

Comment: @PauloScardine My sincere apologies will be much careful from next time as i post a question . As suggested tried both "rAh%19u^l\&G" and pwd = "rAh%19u^l\\&G" both didn't work . i will use the RawConfigParser and then share my results

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like the `%` character is the problem here. It has special meaning if you are using `ConfigParser`. If you are not using interpolation, then use just `RawConfigParser` instead, otherwise you must escape the `%` by doubling it.

When I try the example file with `ConfigParser` it will blow with the following exception:

```
InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%19u^l\\&G"'
```

If I replace `ConfigParser` with `RawConfigParser` everything is fine.

The error you posted has nothing to do with it. We can't even tell if it is a python exception or a shell error message. Please update your question with the full error message. You may also [want to check the `sh` module](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/), a higher level wrapper around `subprocess`.

Comment: ...a big thanks for the answer. This worked. I was searching this since last week. The RawConfigParser just worked fine.

Comment: One is glad to be of service, sire.

Comment: as @Ativerc mentioned, [`RawConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html#configparser.RawConfigParser) is a "Legacy variant of the ConfigParser with interpolation disabled by default and unsafe add_section and set methods."

Comment: Consider using `ConfigParser` instead which checks types of the values to be stored internally. If you don’t want interpolation, you can use `ConfigParser(interpolation=None)`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding up on Paulo Scardine's comment.

if you have special characters that need to be handled, you can set the `ConfigParser`'s `interpolation` argument to `None` and you won't have the error anymore. `ConfigParser` has `interpolation` set  to `BasicInterpolation()` by default.

You can read more about this here:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values

Further, as per the docs `RawConfigParser` is a `Legacy variant of the ConfigParser with interpolation disabled by default and unsafe add_section and set methods.`

Here's a snippet from there:

Example:

```
[Paths]
home_dir: /Users
my_dir: %(home_dir)s/lumberjack
my_pictures: %(my_dir)s/Pictures
```

In the example above, ConfigParser with interpolation set to BasicInterpolation() would resolve `%(home_dir)s` to the value of `home_dir` (/Users in this case). `%(my_dir)s` in effect would resolve to `/Users/lumberjack`. [....]

With interpolation set to `None`, the parser would simply return `%(my_dir)s/Pictures` as the value of `my_pictures` and `%(home_dir)s/lumberjack` as the value of `my_dir`.

Comment: `parser = ConfigParser(interpolation=None)`

Answer (score 1):

you could escape the special char with same char. for example, to be able to read % you have to write it %%

Comment: How does this work with a single quote `'`? I have an apostrophe in a folders name, but configparser can't seem to parse this

Answer (score 1):

I had came across this same issue. Understandably the answer has been posted. Using the comments from everyone on this post I had resolved this issue with the following:

My password was `Sgf%ts54hhGtrf&yhgf`

alembic ini file I was using: `sqlalchemy.url = driver://myuser:Sgf%ts54hhGtrf&yhgf@localhost/my_application`

Error received: `configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(',` which informs me the special character is '%'

Resolved the issue by just wrapping the password in a single quote and doubled the % symbol as recommended from comments in this post to end up with:

```
sqlalchemy.url = driver://myuser:'Sgf%%ts54hhGtrf&yhgf'@localhost/my_application
```

No need to worry about changing the `ConfigParser` as long as you stick to the rule of wrapping the password containing special characters with a single quote and any special characters found in the error you receive to double it e.g. if the error is related to a `%`, add another and end up with `%%`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python version 3.11.4.

By specifying **raw=True** when reading the ini file, it can read special characters as they are.

e.g pwd = config.get('DEFAULT', 'pwd', **raw=True**)

This is the sample abc.ini

```
[DEFAULT]
username=rahul
pwd=rAh%19u^l\&G
```

The following is the Python script:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("abc.ini")

username = config.get('DEFAULT', 'username')
pwd = config.get('DEFAULT', 'pwd', raw=True)

print("username is",username)
print("pwd is",pwd)
```

Output:

```
username is rahul
pwd is rAh%19u^l\&G
```